# Possibility of only dealing with specific region of binary image

Tags: image-processing, flood-fill

Recently I study the image processing.

When I go through the problem of filling the hole, it confuses me (I assume that the people able to answer the question is familiar with the step of doing this so I skip to the problem):

Let's say if I have a binary image like this:

```
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0
      0 0 1 1 0 0 0
      0 1 0 0 1 0 0
      0 1 0 0 1 0 0
      0 0 1 0 1 0 0
      0 0 1 0 1 0 0
      0 1 0 0 0 1 0
      0 1 0 0 0 1 0
      0 1 1 1 1 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

And the book says to start form the region that is inside of the hole and perform the dilation operation and set the bound in case it fills the whole image.

I have no problem understanding the whole process, but if I try to code it, how can I only deal with a specific region (in the hole for this  case)? Or the actual implement would be different method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can assume that the object with holes does not touch the border of the image, you can create an intermediate image where you call flood fill (with value e.g. 2) on the top left pixel. Any remaining '0' pixels have to be inside the contour. Take the position of the first encountered remaining '0' pixel and flood fill it in the original image.

Comment: Ok,I assume that i have multiple zeros outside the object and the zeros distribution are not symmetric for example I have m zeros above the object and n zeros below the object how can I do the intermediate image .I am looking for the general solution of this kind of problem. Thanks

Comment: Make a copy of the original image, call this the intermediate image. In this intermediate image, use flood fill on any border pixel (e.g. top left) with some value other than background and foreground value (e.g. 2). This way, the complete exterior around your object will be filled with 2s. If you then search the intermediate image for a zero, it MUST be inside your object. Hence, if you then return to the original image and call flood fill on the position where you found the interor 0, only the interior of your original object is filled. This is the complete solution.